# How to skip Python Google App Script script authentication?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a funtion that runs an Apps script macro on Google sheets. The apps script is deployed as an API excecutable. The original plan is to deploy the code to a scheduler. The code would basically extract some data from a database and push it to Google Sheets and run a macro to format the output.

The issue I am facing is every time I run the script, it asks me to authenticate, and only after that it executes the script, which means I wouldnt be able to deploy the script for an end to end automation.

```
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",  
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request', 
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly', 
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts", 
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.processes",  
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request', 
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp',]

script_id = "AKfycbxtDnDYa2mTZKB6WoqK_D9PDsLZyqb7GQAh7pvER-K-rMFXYNa6oVOhzXHsyfyl8vLz"
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
service = build("script", "v1", credentials=creds)

  # Create an execution request object.
request = {"function": "helloWorld"} 
service.scripts().run(body=request, scriptId=script_id).execute()
response = service.scripts().run(scriptId=script_id, body=request).execute()
```

What would be a workaround for this?

I tried experimenting with scopes but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: The code you are using is intended for developers and not for real apps. Google App Scripts requires a user account for authorization (OAuth 2.0 Access Token). Obtaining that token requires authenticating a user in a web browser. You could write one Cloud Function that downloads JavaScript to the user's web browser, performs authentication, extracts the token, and then calls another Cloud Function that runs your script.  However, that makes using a scheduler not possible. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

Comment: There are ways to cheat. Your demo code creates tokens. If you save the access token and refresh token, you can run the code in Cloud Functions until the refresh token expires or is revoked. I store the tokens on Google Cloud Storage that the function reads on invocation. Refer to this sample code to see how to store and load saved tokens. You would need to modify it to store the tokens in Cloud Storage. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python#configure_the_sample

Comment: When the refresh token expires or is revoked (which I must monitor via logging or email message), I recreate the tokens and save them in Cloud Storage. Not production worthy, but gets the job done for some applications.

Comment: In your situation, using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script is included in your expected result? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) I thought that when the Web Apps is used, you can execute Google Apps Script with the access token retrieved from the service account. By this, the access token can be retrieved without authorizing the scopes by the browser. I guessed that this might be your expected result. But, if this was not included in your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike You're absolutely right! All I had to do was use token.json I had no clue what that was doing. This solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Aditya J Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue is resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to use was token file

```
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def run_apps_script(script_id, function_name):
  """Calls the Apps Script API."""
  creds = None
  # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
  # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
  # time.
  if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
  # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
          "credentials.json", SCOPES
      )
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
      token.write(creds.to_json())

  try:
    service = build("script", "v1", credentials=creds)

    # Call the Apps Script API
    # Create a new project
    script_id = script_id
    request = {"function": function_name}
    service.scripts().run(body=request, scriptId=script_id).execute()

   
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    # The API encountered a problem.
    print(error.content)
```